# Writing text from Excel 2007 to a .txt file on a Sharepoint Site causes Run-Time error'76' Path not found

Tags: sharepoint, excel, vba

I have this VBA sub in an Excel 2007 project. It records user name, report name, date, and version on a .txt file in a Sharepoint site.  Some of my users are getting a `Run-Time error'76' Path not found` issue.

Here's my code:

```
Sub logReport(ReportName As String)

    Call AppendTxt("//myaviall/teamsites/AviallReportingSolutions/Airplane_Usage_Log/Airplane_ACT.txt", UNameWindows & ";" & ReportName & ";" & Now & ";" & VersionNum)

    Dim oFS, TS, FileObj

    'Get text stream
    'Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Set FileObj = oFS.GetFile("//myaviall/teamsites/AviallReportingSolutions/Airplane_Usage_Log/Airplane_ACT.txt")
    'Set TS = FileObj.OpenAsTextStream(8, -2) 'ForWriting, TristateUseDefault)

    ' Write to file

    'TS.WriteLine UNameWindows & ";" & ReportName & ";" & Now & ";" & VersionNum
    'TS.Close

    'Set TS = Nothing
    'Set FileObj = Nothing
    'Set oFS = Nothing

End Sub

Function AppendTxt(sFile As String, sText As String)
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
 
    FileNumber = FreeFile                   ' Get unused file number
    Open sFile For Append As #FileNumber    ' Connect to the file
    Print #FileNumber, sText                ' Append our string
    Close #FileNumber                       ' Close the file

Exit_Err_Handler:
    Exit Function
 
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: AppendTxt" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    GoTo Exit_Err_Handler
End Function
```

Comment: do those users have access to the sharepoint site?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one user that is getting the issue the first thing that I would look at it access, as Scott points out.

I run a very similar procedure which writes a line to a csv file from outlook based on the code here
http://www.devhut.net/2011/06/06/vba-append-text-to-a-text-file/

This is probably not your answer but if the access is ok then it couldnt hurt to try another method.

**Update**

I also include this into my code to test if the file exists

```
exists = Dir$(sFile) <> fileName
```

Where fileName = "Airplane_ACT.txt" But I would maybe try this with a msgBox to see what it returns.

Also try try changing your string to Airplane_ACT_test.txt and run the code, this should create a new txt file, if this is the case then the issue may be related to your initial txt file.

Last thing: try with a different path eg: to the user's desktop.

Comment: Ryan, Thank you for your response.  The issue happens with multiple users and I've verified their access. So another method might be my next step.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ryan, I tried your method and my test user received Error 76, path not found.  Here's my code:

Comment: Does your new code work on your machine? and have you tested that the user can open the file that the user can open the file using windows explorer?

Comment: I had one of the users look for the path using Windows Explorer and it came right up. So the machine is finding it, but just not when running the macro. Any ideas?

Comment: Well that leaves me a little stumped, if the code works for you, the users have the same access level as you and can navigate to the file then theoretically it all should work.
Im assuming that the code is crashing on
Open sFile For Append As #FileNumber

Comment: Yes it is, and I've tried several things and nothing seems to work. It's quite frustrating.